# Is there a simple and clean way to convert `DATE` to the `TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE` of that date at midnight UTC?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timezone

This should be really simple, but I'm having an embarrassing amount of trouble with it.

In PostgreSQL 9.1, I need to intepret a field stored as a `DATE` in the DB as if it were a `TIMESTAMPTZ` representing midnight UTC on that date. I'd like to do it in a clean and readable way that someone can come along, look at, and understand what's happening.

The only ways I've found to do it so far are both very ugly. One converts it to a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` then creates a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` from it by interpreting it as if it were UTC:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE '2012-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'utc'
```

The other way is worse:

```
('2012-01-01'::date)::timestamptz - (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - current_timestamp)
```

in that it converts the date to a timestamp for midnight local time, then subtracts the time zone offset. I couldn't find any way to get that offset as an interval natively (which seems crazy) so I landed up getting it by comparing `current_timestamp` in local time with `current_timestamp` in UTC.

The only other way I could work out used `extract` to get the date parts and assembled a new `timestamptz` from them. I won't even show that one, it's too ugly.

Both approaches feel all kinds of weird and wrong. Is there any sane way - standard or no - to convert in a readable and easily understood way from a `DATE` to a `timestamptz` of midnight UTC on that date?

I'm looking for something like (imaginary, won't work)

```
'2012-01-01'::date AS TIMESTAMPTZ IN TIME ZONE '00:00';
```

or

```
to_timestamp('2012-01-01'::date, '00:00'::time, 'UTC');
```

Please point out the stupidly obvious thing I'm missing.

Note that I'm testing to make sure the date is truly right internally, not just at display, with `extract(epoch from $1)` where `$1` is the converted date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach is correct. And it's not that ugly, is it? In simplified Postgres syntax:

```
SELECT '2012-1-1'::date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Applied to a variable or column it looks even more elegant:

```
SELECT mydate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

If you are going to enter the date manually, you can shortcut to:

```
SELECT '2012-1-1 0:0'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

The result will always be *displayed* according to the local timezone of the client (i.e. with the according offset), but that has no influence on the *value*.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the `TIMESTAMP` type because of its odd and often ugly behaviour, but if it's the best way to do the job that's fine. Thanks.

Comment: By feeding the `timestamp` to `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` you convert the ugly duckling to `timestamptz` immediately and never have to face ugliness. :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I was just quite surprised that it seems to be necessary to use `timestamp` to do something like this with `timestamptz`; it makes `timestamptz` feel under-specified or incomplete. In the process I noticed that the docs don't appear to say anything about whether casting `date` to `timestamptz` produces local time or utc (either could make sense) so I'll have to propose a docs patch for that.

Comment: If you leave away the cast to `timestamp`, and just do:
`SELECT '2012-1-1'::date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';` the date is converted to `timestamptz` implicitly and you have the *reversed* effect with `AT TIME ZONE`, the same as: `SELECT '2012-1-1'::date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';` Gives you the the "local" timestamp at UTC when it is midnight at your time zone. So, the cast to `timestamp` is essential. And yes, stating that in the docs would help.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I don't know much about PSQL, but I've some experience with date/time matters.

Your first way feels right to me. You're effectively going from "local date" to "local date/time" to "date/time in a particular time zone". Those are all reasonable steps, and ones I'd expect to see in normal date/time APIs.

This approach never introduces the system default time zone as far as I can tell, which is a thoroughly good thing. It performs one logical step at a time, assuming that the cast the sensible thing.

You don't need to worry about the local date/time being either ambiguous or missing in the target time zone, as UTC doesn't have any DST transitions.

Basically, it looks fine. If it works and performs as well as you need it to, I'd stick with it.

Comment: The current timezone of the client is only involved in rendering the result, which will be displayed according to it. It won't influence the value.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: That's my point - it's a good thing not to introduce any other time zones here.

Comment: And I agree. Some people might be confused because they *see* an influence of the local timezone in the result - but the value itself is not influenced.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Of course, if they want to *present* the result in terms of UTC, they could set their connection's time zone to UTC or they could wrap one of your answers like this: `SELECT ('2012-1-1'::date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';` or even the very odd-looking: `SELECT '2012-1-1'::date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I was mainly trying to avoid mixing `timestamp` and `timestamptz`, having generally got the impression `timestamp` was somewhat of a legacy and quirky type to be avoided. If it's the best approach I'm fine with that; I can always wrap it up in an SQL function with an informative name.